# Refresh parent parent page after child closed

Tags: javascript, php

to refresh parent page when children page is closed I usually use the following javascript code:

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

But now, let's say I wanted to refresh the parent parent page once we close the child window. In clear words:

From the page `index.php` I open a page that is called `1.php`

In `1.php` the user is able to review specific informations related to the link he clicked in the page index.php

Now, the user click on a link in page `1.php` that open `2.php` (and allow user to do a modification).  Once the user submit the form of `2.php` I want to:

1. close the page `2.php`
2. refresh page `1.php`
3. refresh page `index.php`

I'm having problem with the last step (point 3).  Is there a way to accomplish that in javascript ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it would be the topmost window, and you could use [**window.top**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.top)

```
window.top.location.reload();
```

You should also be able to just chain `opener` or `parent`

```
window.parent.parent.location.reload();
```